# What's another name for the integral function?

Tags: calculus, terminology, convention

I know this is certainty a basic question, but I'm wondering what you could use as an alternate name for the integral of a function. That is to say; $$\text{In } \int f(x)dx=F(x) \text{, } f(x) \text{ is the integrand} $$
$$\text{What would you call } F(x)? $$

I apologise for asking such a basic question, but I was unable to find any information about this online (although I suspect that's most likely due to my own inability to adequately word my queries)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Antiderivative?

Comment: and some call it a [primitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative)

Comment: An integral?...

Answer (score 0):

Antiderivatives can be used to compute definite integrals, using the fundamental theorem of calculus: if $F$ is an antiderivative of the integrable function $f$ over the interval $[a,b]$, then:

$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)\tag1$$

Because of this, each of the infinitely many antiderivatives of a given function $f$ is sometimes called the "general integral" or "indefinite integral" of $f$ and is written using the integral symbol with no bounds:

$$\int f(x)dx\tag2$$

If $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, and the function $f$ is defined on some interval, then every other antiderivative $G$ of $f$ differs from F by a constant: there exists a number $c$ such that $G(x)=F(x)+c$ for all $x$. $c$ is called the constant of integration.